# When is a finite $R$-algebra isomorphic to $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a $\bar{k}$-algebra (of finite type or complete) reduced (and maybe integral, if needed), let $A$ be an $R$-algebra, finite as an $R$-module, reduced and connected and such that there exists a section $\mathrm{id}_R \colon R \rightarrow A \rightarrow R$. Is it true that $R \cong A$? If $R$ is an algebraically closed field, this is true (the section is not even needed), it is also true if $A$ is integral, but what in general (certainly we need at least the sections, or integral extensions of rings come to mind)?

Comment: Have a look at Zariski's Main Theorem.

Comment: Which version of ZMT are you referring to in particular? I don't want to assume that $R$ is normal. I think I can prove that if $R$ is noetherian and integral, and $R \rightarrow A$ is reduced and has a section $A \rightarrow R$, and $A$ is generically over $R$ connected, then it should follow $R \cong A$. If someone could confirm this result, it would be great. Otherwise, I might post my (attempted) proof soon.

Comment: If you don't want to assume $R$ is normal, then ZMT won't help. If you post your attempted answer, someone might be able to see whether it's correct or not.